# label double arrows in both directions

Tags: math-mode, formatting, arrows, labels

How can I do something like this

```
$L_1 \xrightarrow[\alpha]{\xleftarrow{\gamma}}L_2$
```

where both arrows are of the same length?

Comment: Is `$L_1 \xleftrightharpoons[\gamma]{\alpha} L_2$` acceptable? (might need the `mathtools` package instead of `amsmath`)

Comment: @HenriMenke Good call, but unfortunately not in this particular case. I'm trying to get that into Freeplane which - unfortuantely - does not come with mathtools (or at least I have not yet found an option that would allow me to use ``xleftrightharpoons``).

Answer (score 2):

The excellent `Mathmode` document  explains how to make extensible arrows of all kinds (§38; pp.78-79). Here is an `xleftrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xlongleftrightarrow[2][]{%
\ext@arrow 0059{\longleftrightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}%
}
\def\longleftrightarrowfill@{%
\arrowfill@ ← \relbar → }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  A \xlongleftrightarrow[\quadα\quad]{γ\quadχ}B%
  \xlongleftrightarrow[\alpha]{γ} C \xlongleftrightarrow[ζ\,η\,θ\,ι\,\varkappa]{\,α\,β\,γ\,δ\,ε\,}D
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I'd prefer two arrows to avoid ambiguity. Doesn't have to be straight arrows, if that helps.

Comment: It seems I had misunderstood what you were asking for…

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants left/right harpoons?

Comment: I really have no idea.