# How to write over a double-ended arrow

Tags: math-mode, arrows, stacking-symbols

I've come across how to write over a left or right facing arrow but not one that's double-ended. I tried this below (but with `\` in front of both `[` and `]` but for some reason this won't typeset here) but it doesn't work so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
\[ a \xleftrightarrow{\text{x}} b \]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I've tried removing the x after the backslash however this just means the other x isn't above the arrows, simply next to it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE) illustrating the issue.

Comment: You can look at the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322166/label-double-arrows-in-both-directions/322173#322173), which defines precisely such a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123219/writing-above-and-below-a-symbol-simultaneously
\newcommand\stackleftrightarrow[1]{%
    \mathrel{{\stackon[4pt]{$\leftrightarrow$}{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}}}
\begin{document}
    $   a \stackleftrightarrow{x} b$
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

A more generalised approach would be to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}



\newcommand{\xrightarrowdbl}[2][]{%
    \leftarrow\mathrel{\mkern-14mu}\xrightarrow[#1]{#2}
}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260554/two-headed-version-of-xrightarrow
\begin{document}
    $x \xrightarrowdbl{\text{a}} y$\\
    $x \xrightarrowdbl{\text{your text}} y$
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you! I'll give that a go when I can access my work again later tonight:)

Comment: @Janitt you are welcome, if you find the answer useful, consider accepting it.